# Understanding "mdmc_reduce" parameter using torchmetrics F1 Score

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to understand how to use the parameter `mdmc_reduce` when calculating F1 Score using torchmetrics in a multi-class classification problem (12 classes).

I have:

```
#y_pred -> Output probabilities
y_pred = torch.tensor([[0.0793, 0.1140, 0.1216, 0.0727, 0.0671, 0.0810, 0.0646, 0.0759, 0.1108,
         0.0600, 0.0578, 0.0952],
        [0.0830, 0.1252, 0.0985, 0.0736, 0.0722, 0.0839, 0.0734, 0.0721, 0.1242,
         0.0516, 0.0636, 0.0788],
        [0.0779, 0.1169, 0.1129, 0.0715, 0.0713, 0.0930, 0.0693, 0.0786, 0.1065,
         0.0591, 0.0577, 0.0856]]) 

# y_true -> One-hot encoded labels
y_true = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then I convert the output probabilities into a one-hot encoded vector to compare with the y_true:

```
predictions = torch.argmax(y_pred, dim=1)
one_hot_predictions = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(predictions, num_classes=12)
```

then I try to calculate the F1-micro and macro scores using the following line of code:

```
f1_micro = F1(average='micro')
f1_macro = F1(num_classes=12, average='macro')
print(f"F1 Micro: {f1_micro(one_hot_predictions, y_true)}")
print(f"F1 Macro: {f1_macro(one_hot_predictions, y_true)}")
```

but when I try to execute this I have an error saying that I need to use `mdmc_reduce='samplewise' or mdmc_reduce='global'`.

- What's the difference between these two arguments? Which one I need to choose?
- and another question is if I need to convert the `y_pred` into one-hot encoded vector to calculate the F1 Score or it's not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

for your first question about mdmc_reduce:

```
'samplewise': In this case, the statistics are computed separately for each sample on the N axis, and then the outputs are concatenated together. In each sample the extra axes ... are flattened to become the sub-sample axis, and statistics for each sample are computed by treating the sub-sample axis as the N axis for that sample.

'global': In this case the N and ... dimensions of the inputs are flattened into a new N_X sample axis, i.e. the inputs are treated as if they were (N_X, C). From here on the reduce parameter applies as usual.
```

you can read more [here](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/stat_scores.html#stat-scores)

You don't need to convert to one hot encode for calculating the [F1 Score](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classification/f1_score.html?highlight=F1%20score#f1-score).

The best place to ask questions for TorchMetrics is the [Lightning AI GH discussion](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/metrics/discussions)